# How to convert mysql sentence to adding specific number for values

Tags: mysql, regex, sed

I have four huge mysql tables that holding region, country, city and street informations and i can call them by a php code properly. So what i want to do is merge them into one table. I have already the data for all values as shown below for instance,

```
insert  into `table1`(`region_id`,`name`) values (1,'region1'),(2,'region2'),(3,'region3');
insert  into `table2`(`country_id`,`region_id`,`name`) values (1,1,'country1'),(2,1,'country2'),(3,1,'country3');
insert  into `table3`(`city_id`,`country_id`,`name`) values (1,1,'city'),(2,1,'city2'),(3,1,'city3');
insert  into `table4`(`street_id`,`city_id`,`name`) values (1,1,'street1'),(2,1,'street2'),(3,1,'street3');
```

i've figure out that easiest way would be to convert lines as below however, i need to use regular expression, sed or similar to achieve my goal. I am done with php code to call with this structure if i could.

```
insert  into `table`(`id`,`name`) values (1,'region1'),(2,'region2'),(3,'region3');
insert  into `table`(`id`,`parent_id`,`name`) values (1001,1,'country1'),(1002,1,'country2'),(1003,2,'country3');
insert  into `table`(`id`,`parent_id`,`name`) values (5001,1001,'city1'),(5002,1001,'city2'),(5003,1002,'city3');
insert  into `table`(`id`,`parent_id`,`name`) values (10001,5001,'street1'),(10002,5001,'street'),(10003,5002,'street3');
```

Is there any way to convert values as shown above or do you have any better idea to do so ?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: why bother using `sed`? why not just a sql statement? `select region.name, country.name, city.name, street.name from region, country, city, street where region.region_id = country.region_id and country.country_id = city.country_id and city.city_id = street.street_id ?`

Comment: because i've already have comprehensive php code for a specific software it is easy to convert sql statement into one table rather than change whole php code. So that's why i need to put all data into one table.

Comment: do you have access to that mysql server?

Comment: yes i do that i am inserting into. with adding 1000 + n would be much easier for me.

Comment: not fully understand what you are talking about. try mysql command line access that server and run the sql statement. you don't need your php code. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/`table[^`]*`/`table`/;s/`[^_`]*_id`/`id`/' YourFile
```

change:
 - first tablexxx to table
 - first *field*_id to id

just check in your shell that [ ` ] is not interpreted (normally not due to simple quote arround)